# How to add unmanaged Dependendies in Maven when using Git

Tags: eclipse, git, maven

I need to add a single jar to a maven project that is hosted in git.
However this file is not present in any public repository.

I can install the file to my local repository but since there are other people working on the project as well they can't resolve the dependency.
I don't really want to set up a manager for a single dependency, so is there any clean way to add it to my project and still be able to share the project?

I did try to create an repository in the project's path and add it to my pom but maven can'resolve it. Anyway it would look somewhat hackish.

Comment: Setting up a repository manager has many other advantages(like only single location for all dependencies, single location for release your colleagues are made, a central source of your artifacts for deployments) in particular if you are not alone...Best would be a repo manager, second would be [non-maven-jar-plugin](https://github.com/stephenc/non-maven-jar-maven-plugin) and last and most bad is to use system scoped dependency.

Answer (score 1):

```
<dependency>
    <artifactId>**</artifactId>
    <groupId>**</groupId>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/dep.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Comment: If you recommend the use of the `system` scope then you should also state what future problems the OP is for sure going to have.